# Convert integer to Date in node.js

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to convert a integer to a Date using node .js, and Date.

I know that this is a very common question but all the solutions that have been posted before have failed to help me.

I am getting the dates from a json file found at http://api.guardian.gg/chart/elo/4611686018432537994,

Example date: 1461110400000

What I've tried:

```
    var date = String(new Date(elodata.x));
```

and

```
    var date = String(new Date(parseInt(elodata.x)));
```

But I get invalid date as a result.

I realise that this might not be doable because I don't know how guardian.gg handles this data. But you never know.

Comment: could you please include the whole (relevant) code. Especially the part that determines what exactly `elodata` is in your code. My guts somehow tell me that your elodata references the whole array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass in your value directly to a `Date` constructor in Javascript if it is an integer (which it appears to be in :

```
var date = new Date(elodata.x);
```

Likewise, you can also use the the [`setTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) function in Javascript to pass your integer value in if you already have an existing object :

```
var date = new Date();
d.setTime(elodata.x);
```

**Example**

```js
var d1 = new Date(1461110400000);
console.log(`Constructor: ${d1}`);

var d2 = new Date();
d2.setTime(1461110400000);
console.log(`setTime(): ${d2}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

When a single argument is passed to the Date constructor, if it's a string it will be parsed. The result of that is implementation dependent but if 1461110400000 is a string it will almost certainly give an invalid date.

If given a number, it's treated as a time value. So if you're passing a number, make sure it's type number:

```js
var timeValue = '1461110400000';
console.log( new Date(+timeValue));
```

You could also use `Number(timeValue)` or `parseInt(timeValue)` but unary `+` is less to type.