# Convert Excel Date string to Unix time in Node.js

Tags: node.js, xlsx, date-conversion

I use ***node-xlsx*** for parsing *Excel* file in *Node.js* but Date cells have strange view before parsing:

```
in Excel: 01.03.2016 07:44:04
in Node.js before parsing: 42430.32226851852
```

How I can convert this string ***42430.32226851852*** to Unix-time format?

**Update:**
Write myself solution that work for me:

```
var xlsxDate = '42430.32226851852'
var splitDate=xlsxDate.split('.');
var unixTime=new Date(1900, 0, splitDate[0]-1, 0, 0, Math.round(splitDate[1]/1157410)).getTime()/1000
console.log(unixTime)
```

Where *1157410* is ~1 second

Comment: Hello Dan. I think this link can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183859/convert-integer-to-date-in-node-js

Comment: Thanks but not shure. I find information that dot point split 42430.32226851852 to date and time: 42430 - date (from 01.01.1900), 32226851852 - time. And now I dont understend how I can transform 32226851852 to normal time format. Excel is rounded 32226851852 to 32227 when i change cell format from Date to String

Answer (score 1):

i use this code to convert Unix-time format:

```
date = new Date(( parseInt(excelDate) - (25567 + 2))*86400*1000)
unix = date.getTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another work around is that when you save it to your excel document you save it as a string and not a Date object.

Then you can read it as a string and just wrap it in a new Date()